# How common is it for iPhone users to NOT be running iOS 10+?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, auto-update, build-version

I'm building an app in which I want to use a module that works only for iPhones with iOS 10 and above.

I know I can never assume that everyone is using a given version, but I just wanted some insight into how common it might be that someone would be using a version less than 10?

I've always kept my own phone up to date, but I don't know the repercussions and likelihood of someone not updating it.

Comment: A Google search for _ios version market share_ yielded some interesting links. [This one](https://gs.statcounter.com/ios-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/worldwide) has a [CSV download](https://gs.statcounter.com/ios-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/chart.php?device=Mobile%20%26%20Tablet&device_hidden=mobile%2Btablet&multi-device=true&statType_hidden=ios_version&region_hidden=ww&granularity=monthly&statType=iOS%20Version&region=Worldwide&fromInt=201903&toInt=202003&fromMonthYear=2019-03&toMonthYear=2020-03&csv=1)(_direct link_) you might find interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how common it might be that someone would be using a version less than 10?

Based on the publicly shared data by Apple (linked below), a very few percentage of currently active iPhone devices are a version of iOS that's less than 10.

So if your question is along the lines of, ***how many potential users do I lose if I drop support for iOS 9 and earlier***, the answer would be a very few.

This should help you get a perspective:

- [App Store - Support - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)

> [image: iOS and iPadOS Usage]

The webpage is updated by Apple on a regular basis. The statistics are drawn from currently active devices (ones which have an active Internet connection and visits the App Store app).

<sub>The snapshot above is captured at the time of writing the answer.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

[According to Apple as of Jan 2020](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/):

- 77% of all devices **introduced in the last four years** use iOS 13
- 17% of all devices **introduced in the last four** years use iOS 12
- 70% of **all devices** use iOS 13
- 23% of **all devices** use iOS 12

[image]

This is the only breakdown I could find from Apple. Other breakdowns might exist from 3rd party analytic sites.

It looks like there's a very small number of users on iOS 10, based upon n these stats.